# A special integral equation of Volterra type

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations, integral-operators, integral-kernel

Let  $a,f \in L^2(0,t)$ (where $t \leqslant 1$), and consider the following integral equation: 
$$
f(t)\int_0^t a(s)\,ds + \int_0^t a(t - s) f(s) \, ds = 0
$$

> My question is : under what condition on $a$ the unique solution is $f=0$ ?
>   Thanks.

Comment: Is your $a$ positive or not necessarily?

Comment: @fedja The $a$ is not necessarily positive.